# The error view files were not found. Cannot render exception trace. Code Igniter 4

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I can't access my local host (`http://localhost:8081/`).

Error:

```bash
The error view files were not found. Cannot render exception trace.
```

Comment: Did you find the answer(s) helpful?

Answer (score 0):

This error comes from a [*"missing error view file"*](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/0678da2597f22bb7f6ca680af85814a391be03c0/system/Debug/Exceptions.php#L237).

1. Make sure you have all relevant files & directories under [`app/Views/errors/`](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/tree/develop/app/Views/errors).

```
├───app
|   |
│   └───Views
        └───errors
            ├───cli
            │       error_404.php
            │       error_exception.php
            │       production.php
            │
            └───html
                    debug.css
                    debug.js
                    error_404.php
                    error_exception.php
                    production.php
```

2. Ensure that the configuration variable below in the file `app/Config/Exceptions.php` is set correctly.

```php
    /**
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * Error Views Path
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * This is the path to the directory that contains the 'cli' and 'html'
     * directories that hold the views used to generate errors.
     *
     * Default: APPPATH.'Views/errors'
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $errorViewPath = APPPATH . 'Views/errors';
```

Answer (score 0):

Download CI 4.0 and open Views directory and find 'errors' folder then upload 'errors' directory into the existing project's views